# ¿Como editar propiedad de un control de MainWindow desde el Codebehind de un usercontrol en WPF?

Tags: wpf

Lo que quiero básicamente es cambiar la propiedad Visibility del control nav_pnl de mi ventana principal a través de un evento que creé en el codebehind de mi Control de Usuario (LogginMenu). El control de usuario se cierra cuando cierta condición se cumple y cambia la poropiedad a visibile, pero no se como hacerlo...

> Formulario de la ventana MainWindow

```
<Window x:Class="AppGym_v3_.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppGym_v3_"
        xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:AppGym_v3_"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        WindowStyle="None"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Title="Gym" Height="550" Width="700">
    
    <Grid>
        
        <!-- Backgorund Color-->
        <Grid Background="Black">
            
            <!--Navg Panel-->
            <Grid x:Name="nav_pnl"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  Width="40"
                  Background="#2E333A"
                  Visibility="Hidden">
                
                <StackPanel x:Name="st_pnl">
                    <Grid Height="40">
                        
                        <!--Menu Text-->
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                                   Grid.Column="0"
                                   Margin="40 12 0 0"
                                   Text="M E N U"
                                   Foreground="White"
                                   Background="Transparent">
                            
                            <!--Text Effect-->
                            <TextBlock.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10"
                                                  ShadowDepth="1"
                                                  Direction="-90"
                                                  Color="White">
                                </DropShadowEffect>
                            </TextBlock.Effect>
                        </TextBlock>
                        
                        <!--Menu Button-->
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="tg_btn"
                                  Margin="6 5"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                            <ToggleButton.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Unchecked">
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard x:Name="HideStackPanel">
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="nav_pnl"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                                         BeginTime="0:0:00"
                                                         From="150" To="40"
                                                         Duration="0:0:0.2">
                                            </DoubleAnimation>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger>

                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Checked">
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard x:Name="ShowStackPanel">
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="nav_pnl"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                                         BeginTime="0:0:00"
                                                         From="40" To="150"
                                                         Duration="0:0:0.3">
                                            </DoubleAnimation>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger>
                            </ToggleButton.Triggers>

                        </ToggleButton>
                        
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>

            </Grid>
            
            <!--Loggin Menu-->
            <uc:LogginMenu Margin="0 60 0 75"/>

        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Cambiar la propiedad Visibility="Hidden" a Visibility="Visible" desde el método **ButtonLoggin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)**

> CodeBehind de UserControl

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace AppGym_v3_
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for LogginMenu.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class LogginMenu : UserControl
    {
        public LogginMenu()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void acceso()
        {
            
        }
        public void ButtonLoggin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (TextUsuario.Text == "Luis Miguel" && TextContraseña.Password == "Math120100")
            {
                (this.Parent as Grid).Children.Remove(this);
                
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Y qué código tienes? Te sugiero que leas [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Crea un método o propiedad pública en tu UserControl que haga lo que necesitas, luego en el evento llamas al control por el nombre que le pusiste o a través de "sender" y si por ejemplo tu método se llama MiMetodo y el control se llama MiControl lo llamas como a cualquier control común MiControl.MiMetodo(); y listo.. (eso es lo que entiendo de tu pregunta, no se si es lo que quieres, sino explica más detallado)

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya edité mi pregunta y puse parte del código principal. Intenté con lo que me sugirió pero no me funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

Leí nuevamente tu pregunta y creo que la solución que mejor se adapta a tu caso es implementar una Interfaz, esto te permitirá llamar a métodos del MainWindow desde practicamente cualquier clase o control que quieras, lo puedes lograr así:

Primero crea una interfaz que contenga un método que te permita editar la propiedad que quieres, en este caso `Visibility`:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace AppGym_v3_
{
    interface IMyInterface
    {
        void SetVisibility(Visibility value);
    }
}
```

Luego, haz que tu MainWindow implemente esa interfaz:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace AppGym_v3_
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, IMyInterface
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        } 
        
        public void SetVisibility(Visibility value)
        {
            nav_pnl.Visibility = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Y finalmente, haz que tu UserControl también la implemente:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace AppGym_v3_
{
    public partial class LogginMenu : UserControl, IMyInterface
    {
        public LogginMenu()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        } 
        
        public void SetVisibility(Visibility value)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    IMyInterface interfaz = (IMyInterface)Application.Current.MainWindow;
                    if (interfaz != null)
                    {
                        interfaz.SetVisibility(Visibility.Visible);
                    }
                }));
        }
    }
}
```

Y ya con eso puedes llamar a cualquier método en tu MainWindow que esté creado primero en la interfaz.

En tu caso lo puedes llamar desde el botón que definiste:

```
public void ButtonLoggin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SetVisibility(Visibility.Visible); 
}
```

Nótese que al método en el UserControl le agregué el Dispatcher en caso que uses Threads, pero puedes omitirlo si no lo necesitas, de todos modos funcionará bien.

Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Implementé una interfaz como me dijo y pinchó ok